# The value of array must not be a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem with my models for my django project. I'm had to use a `ManyToManyField` to get multiple foreign key but I don't get how it correctly works. I tried to look around the internet, google my mistake but still don't know how to resolve it. Here is the code for the model:

```
class Framework(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    typeOfFramework = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfProgram, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cotationOfFramework = models.IntegerField(default = 5)
    additionalInformation =  models.ForeignKey(web,blank=True,null=True ,default = None ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.name} {0.version} {0.language} {0.typeOfFramework} {0.cotationOfFramework}'
        template.format(self)
```

and here is the code for the admin page:

```
class FrameworkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('name', 'language', 'version', 'typeOfFramework' 
,'additionalInformation','cotationOfFramework')
```

I got this error:

```
(admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[1]' must not be a ManyToManyField.
```

Can anyone help me on how to understand this and make it work?

Thank you all a lot!

Comment: Take `language` out of `list_display` because its an M2M.

Comment: Yes, I saw it works like this but how can I make it so it is visible in the admin page?

Comment: Include it in the field list for the change form. An M2M is more suitable there than in the list view.